# Nested loop for alphabets

Tags: c, loops

How do I go about making a loop that created an array like the following:

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
```

I was thinking about making a loop that loops through a-z, then another one nested inside that loops through a-z, would that be the correct approach? If yes, how do I implement it?

Comment: Do you know how to set up loops in general?  If you can be specific about the part of the loop that confuses you, it would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, your approach is right. Think about how you create a single `for` loop. Then try creating another one inside it.

Comment: you better show your code.

Comment: I tested a few times and I think I got it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question was a bit vague, but from what I can tell, it seems like you understand the concept of loops, but don't know how to apply them to character ranges.  Rather than give anything away, here's a hint.

In C, characters are basically numbers.  So it's legal to add a number to a character to get the next character.

For instance:

```
'a' + 0 == 'a'
'a' + 1 == 'b'
```

And so on.

So think about it... you are using nested loops which count through numbers, and you can loop through characters by adding offsets to them... what do you do next?

Comment: Ya, I tested a few times and I think i got it, mine looked like `for (i='a';i<='z';i++)` and another one inside that. And before this I didn't know I could compare letters, like `i<='z'`. Thanks!

Comment: Watch out that, strictly speaking, in C letters need not necessarily have sequential (numeric) values: i.e. the standard does not guarantee that (for example) `'b' - 'a' == 1`. Though in most cases it will be, one notable counter-example is the [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)-encoding, where `'i' == 137` and `'j' == 145`. It's about 99% likely you won't ever have to deal with that though. On the other hand: the numeric values of digits **are** guaranteed to be sequential, so `'0' + 1 == '1', '1' + 1 == '2'` etc.

Comment: Alright, will keep that in mind, just in case! thanks.
also, another question, lets say i do `char i = 'a'`, what is the difference between that and `char i = "a"`? the latter doesnt work, the error was assignment without cast.

Comment: The single quotes are characters, double quotes are strings.  The above doesn't work with strings, just characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work, but you have a few alternatives, like using itoa and sprintf.